# Web API returns null

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, asp.net-web-api, petapoco

I use .net framework 4, and petapoco to create a my first Web API module in dnn. here is my code:

```
[TableName("TblBPMProcess")]
[PrimaryKey("ProcessID", AutoIncrement = true)]
[Cacheable("ProcessInfo", CacheItemPriority.Default, 20)]
[Scope("ModuleId")]
public class ProcessInfo
{
    public int ProcessID { get; set; }

    public int ModuleID { get; set; }

    public string DynamicModuleID { get; set; }

    public string ProcessCaption { get; set; }

    public int Availability { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }        
}
```

In controller:

```
public IEnumerable<ProcessInfo> GetList(int ModuleID)
{
    IEnumerable<ProcessInfo> item;
    using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
    {
        var rep = ctx.GetRepository<ProcessInfo>();
        item = rep.Get(ModuleID);
    }
        return item;
}
```

In codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cnt = new StateController();
    IEnumerable<StateInfo> lst = cnt.GetList(1);
    rptHostList.DataSource = lst;
}
```

in Page_Load, lst returns null. i double checked all columns and table names. there is neither error nor data. Any Idea?

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on `return item;`, does it have an object when you call the controller?

Comment: So the problem lies _before_ returning the result by the Web API? It's difficult to say what would cause that without seeing what your repository looks like (to start with).

Comment: Are you using an ObjectQualifier in your DNN install?

Comment: no i don't. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the method may return an `IEnumerable` with items or `null` (if there is no items).

So all what you need to do is check if the returned value is not null:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cnt = new StateController();
    IEnumerable<StateInfo> lst = cnt.GetList(1);

    if (lst != null)
    {
        rptHostList.DataSource = lst;
    }
}
```

Comment: my problem is WHY it returns null when there are some records in table. it should return data.

Answer (score 0):

In `[Scope("ModuleId")]` , I believe that puts in the current ModuleId instead of the one you are passing in.

You may want to comment that out or change it, and see if it works.  It may be getting it confused some how.

Comment: that cnt.GetList(1) was just as test, i tried cnt.GetList(This.ModuleId) too. it doesn't work!

Comment: @maryammohammadi I'm thinking that when you do your Get(somenumber), its actually looking at the PrimaryKey "ProcessId" instead of the ModuleId. I'm not really familiar with PetaPoco, but in other ORMs I've worked on, a basic Get(x) is using PrimaryKey. If you want to search by ModuleId, you'll have to write something like, GetByModuleId(moduleid). I'd step thru and try something that would test that out.